# Metaclass conflicts with a static method in c++ python extension

Tags: cpython

I am currently writing a python extension which contains a number of classes. I have encountered an unexpected behavior when compiling my extension against python 3.8 (it works fine in python 2.7). When my custom type definition uses a metaclass and provides a static method(s), such static method becomes difficult to call. Calling simply `Foo.bar()` causes a `TypeError: 'staticmethod' object is not callable` exception. I have produced a minimal example which reproduces that behavior in python 3.8:

```
#include <Python.h>

static PyModuleDef foomodule = {
    PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
    "foo",
    "Foo module",
    -1, 0, 0, 0, 0
};

struct foo_FooObject {
    PyObject_HEAD
};

static PyObject* foo_Foo_bar( PyObject *self, PyObject *args )
{
    return self;
}

static PyMethodDef fooMethods[] = {
    { "bar", foo_Foo_bar, METH_STATIC | METH_VARARGS, "Foo.bar()" },
    { NULL, NULL, 0, NULL }
};

static PyTypeObject fooMetaType = {
    PyVarObject_HEAD_INIT( &PyType_Type, 0 )
    "Foometa",
    sizeof(PyTypeObject),
    0,
    0,                                // tp_dealloc
    0,                                // tp_print
    0,                                // tp_getattr
    0,                                // tp_setattr
    0,                                // tp_compare
    0,                                // tp_repr
    0,                                // tp_as_number
    0,                                // tp_as_sequence
    0,                                // tp_as_mapping
    0,                                 // tp_hash
    0,                                // tp_call
    0,                                 // tp_str
    0,          // tp_getattro
    0,          // tp_setattro
    0,                                // tp_as_buffer
    Py_TPFLAGS_DEFAULT,               // tp_flags
    0,                                // tp_doc
    0,                                // tp_traverse
    0,                                // tp_clear
    0,                                // tp_richcompare
    0,                                // tp_weaklistoffset
    0,                                // tp_iter
    0,                                // tp_iternext
    0,                                // tp_methods
    0,                                // tp_members
    0,                                // tp_getset
    &PyType_Type,                     // tp_base
    0,                                // tp_dict
    0,                                // tp_descr_get
    0,                                // tp_descr_set
    0,                                // tp_dictoffset
    0,                                // tp_init
    0,                                // tp_alloc
    0,                                // tp_new
    0,                                // tp_free
    0,                                // tp_is_gc
    0,                                // tp_bases
    0,                                // tp_mro
    0,                                // tp_cache
    0,                                // tp_subclasses
    0                                 // tp_weaklist
    , 0 // tp_del
    , 0 // tp_version_tag
    , 0 // tp_finalize
};

static PyTypeObject foo_FooType = {
    PyVarObject_HEAD_INIT(&fooMetaType, 0)
    "foo.Foo",                 /* tp_name */
    sizeof(foo_FooObject),     /* tp_basicsize */
    0,                         /* tp_itemsize */
    0,                         /* tp_dealloc */
    0,                         /* tp_print */
    0,                         /* tp_getattr */
    0,                         /* tp_setattr */
    0,                         /* tp_compare */
    0,                         /* tp_repr */
    0,                         /* tp_as_number */
    0,                         /* tp_as_sequence */
    0,                         /* tp_as_mapping */
    0,                         /* tp_hash */
    0,                         /* tp_call */
    0,                         /* tp_str */
    0,                         /* tp_getattro */
    0,                         /* tp_setattro */
    0,                         /* tp_as_buffer */
    Py_TPFLAGS_DEFAULT,        /* tp_flags */
    "foo.Foo object",          /* tp_doc */
    0,                                // tp_traverse
    0,                                // tp_clear
    0,                                // tp_richcompare
    0,                                // tp_weaklistoffset
    0,                                // tp_iter
    0,                                // tp_iternext
    0,                                // tp_methods
    0,                                // tp_members
    0,                                // tp_getset
    0,                                // tp_base
    0,                                // tp_dict
    0,                                // tp_descr_get
    0,                                // tp_descr_set
    0,                                // tp_dictoffset
    0,                                // tp_init
    0,                                // tp_alloc
    0,                                // tp_new
    0,                                // tp_free
    0,                                // tp_is_gc
    0,                                // tp_bases
    0,                                // tp_mro
    0,                                // tp_cache
    0,                                // tp_subclasses
    0                                 // tp_weaklist
    , 0 // tp_del
    , 0 // tp_version_tag
    , 0 // tp_finalize
};


PyMODINIT_FUNC PyInit_foo()
{
    PyObject* foo = PyModule_Create( &foomodule );
    if ( foo == NULL ) {
        return NULL;
    }
    
    if ( PyType_Ready( &fooMetaType ) < 0 ) {
         return NULL;
    }
    
    foo_FooType.tp_methods = fooMethods;
    if ( PyType_Ready( &foo_FooType ) < 0 ) {
         return NULL;
    }

    Py_INCREF( &foo_FooType );
    PyModule_AddObject( foo, "Foo", (PyObject *)&foo_FooType );

    return foo;
}
```

After compiling the extension and importing it, I would expect to be able
to say:

```
from foo import Foo
Foo.bar()
```

It works fine if I do not use metaclass, (ie.replace the `&fooMetaType` with `NULL` in the `foo_FooType` definition). Am I doing something wrong here? Can I even combine metaclasses with static methods, or is this not possible for some reason?